# Browsing history windows 10

Tags: windows, history, web

I need to find a website that I visited with chrome but unfortunately the history is not old enough because it was cleared after visiting this site.
Is there any another windows registry that contains the history of the sites visited that can be consulted?

Comment: How far back does your backup software go? That's where your answer lies. No backup, no history… you wiped it. Long-shot alternative - do you have full admin access to your router's history? [Most consumer routers don't store this, but some do]

Comment: I am hesitant to even ask my question, but when you indicate "after visiting this site.", what site are you referring to exactly?

Comment: yes, I have full access. it's my home pc.

Comment: Your router's history is not stored in your computer, it's stored in your router… if at all.

Comment: I know this but it is obvious that I have access to the router of my home PC

Comment: does anything change if I tell you what site it is? or is it pure curiosity?

Comment: Rather than being concerned over what site it may have been, have you started looking at your router logs to see if it stores that history; or looked back through your ordinary computer backups to that date??

Comment: yes, there is no backup, no restore point, no previous version.
Ok as soon as I can into the router but I'm not very confident about it.

Answer (score 0):

Some measures that might help, although the chances are slim:

- If you are logged-in to Google, browse to
  [My Google Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity)
- Restore by using the Previous Version mechanism of Windows:

  1. Find your Google Chrome location, usually
     `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Goolge\Chrome`
  2. Right click on User Data folder and hit "Restore previous versions"
     from the menu
  3. Choose the desired version and click the Restore button.
- A weak method is to enter in the Command Prompt (cmd) the command 
  `ipconfig/displaydns`.
  This will list websites that you have visited (but not pages), which might
  jog your memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately, there is no previous version. And the browser was not logged in. I will try with the third method.